# Replace string including asterisk in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace the same string `*a*a` consistently with `*a`.

Tried many variations of something like this, but none really worked:

`s = s.replace( /\b*a*a\b/g, "*a");`

So far running this leads to all `xzy*a` being replaced with `xyz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is a special regex character.  If you want to match only an actual asterisk, then you have to escape it like this:

```
s = s.replace( /\*a\*a/g, "*a");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gvgshwyz/

Answer (score 0):

An asterisk is a special regex character.

You just have to escape it like this: `\*a` in place of `*a`